# Tabs vs. Home Screen For Android Application?

Tags: android, user-interface, interface-design

I have an Android application that I've been working on, and it's implemented using tabs to separate the different functions that it performs.

[See the article here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html)

The above article talks about how instead of implementing the Twitter application using tabs they decided to go with a home screen and a tool bar because of some of the limitations of tabs.

If my application only ever would need to have three tabs (or 3 home screen icons) would it be worth it for me to take the time to go back and convert my application to a home screen layout, or is home screen versus tab purely a preference?

[image: Home Screen Example]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_GTM_W5mVPTU/S-rlV2NLU0I/AAAAAAAAAD0/fQUmdTS6cdA/s400/home01.png))</sub>

Home Screen Example
[image: Tabs Example]
<sub>(source: [simplydroid.com](http://www.simplydroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/site14.png))</sub>

Tabs Example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a matter of preference, but is also dependant on your application layout.  For some applications the screen space that would otherwise be devoted to tabs could be better utilized.

Comment: So in terms of functionality they are roughly equivalent, but using the home screen approach would net me more real estate for my lists.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to get this question answered is to post some screenshots of your app. There is no generic answer to the "tabs vs. home screen" question.

Without seeing the app, I'd say you are fine.  If its only 3 tabs, and tabs felt logical at the time, then there is probably nothing to worry about.

Comment: Yeah it looks like the main difference is screen space for the user. I'd prefer to have the best possible experience for the user so I guess I'll start converting from tabs to the home screen style.

Answer (score 1):

Do a prototype of it working both ways.

Then find a selection of people that would use your app and find out what they prefer.

Answer (score 1):

As Google designers point out, the `dashboard` pattern is what you are asking for, [watch this session](http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/android-ui-design-patterns.html) from last Google I/O to better understand what they are talking about.